# bundler_version_finder.rb:80:in `pwd': Operation not permitted - getcwd (Errno::EPERM)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to run a cron task using whenever gem with rails task but keep getting this error on the logfile:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:80:in `pwd': Operation not permitted - getcwd (Errno::EPERM)
```

I am using rbenv version: 2.6.0, rails 5

Comment: Hey, were you able to fix this issue? I'm having the same one but with RVM.

Comment: The same!! help please, do you find any solution? What I noticed strange is that even using an updated version with RVM, the error persists in the previous version, I don't know what to do! I have the problem with the version of Ruby 3.0.0

Comment: Hi, I posted this a long time ago. I am no longer using rails, but if I remember right, it had to do with rbenv version. Good luck